# where does the class facade will be in my directory MVC?

Tags: php, design-patterns, facade

I have a question related to design patterns, I am developing an MVC app in php, but I dont know where will be the class facade, if I am using an mvc pattern, I think that the facade have to be in the model, but I dont know??, where to put the class facade?

```
**model**
DeliveryDepartment.php
DiscountDepartment.php
OrderDepartment.php
PizzaCallCenterFacade.php
**view**
**controller**
```

or I have tp put the facade in another folder? how do you organize the dessing pattern facade with MVC?

thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) implementation, than this class has to stay together with models, since it "facades" other model classes.

Comment: correct. Facades are created to reduce complexity. It belongs in the model.

Comment: @yegor256 thanks for answering, if I use an mvc framework like zend the design patterns should be in the helpers folder or in another folder?

Comment: "design patterns" are not classes, they can't _"be in a folder"_. [Model-view-controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is also a design pattern, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new directory called **components**. thats where I stick extra classes that are not model views or controllers. Maybe call it helper if thats what it is.

```
**components**
facade.php 
**model**
DeliveryDepartment.php
DiscountDepartment.php
OrderDepartment.php
PizzaCallCenterFacade.php
**view**
**controller**
```

Comment: thanks for answering, if I use an mvc framework like zend the design patterns should be in the helpers folder or in another folder?